# Oracle show columns as row

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

How can i convert multiple column to row accoding by followed sample? For solution, i inspected many sample for example pivot, decode etc. but i did not reach absolute solution.

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  COL_1  |  COL_2  |  COL_3  |  COL_4  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+

I wanna make columns like this;    

+---------+
|  COL_1  |
+---------+
|  COL_2  |
+---------+
|  COL_3  |
+---------+
|  COL_4  |
+---------+
```

Comment: Show what have you tried. Where is your query.

Comment: for what? to show values for each column in linline rows ?

Comment: `select col_1 from the_table union all select col_2 from the_table ...`

Comment: `select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='MyTableName';`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you wanted `unpivot`?

```
with demo as ( select 1 as col1, 2 as col2, 3 as col3, 4 as col4 from dual )
select * from demo
unpivot
( colvalue for col in (col1, col2, col3, col4) );

COL    COLVALUE
---- ----------
COL1          1
COL2          2
COL3          3
COL4          4

4 rows selected.
```

Comment: is there a way not to specify the col name? For  example, for any n:  select 1, 2, 3,  ..., n from dual; Its result is a row. How to show the result as rows? Thanks.

Comment: There is no way around having to specify the unpivot list, if that's what you mean.

Comment: btw pivot/unpivot are only available in Oracle 11g +

Answer (score 0):

btw if anyone like me is searching for a quick and dirty way to show a transposed row somewhere - e.g. in Word or Excel, it would be easier to just export the rows normally e.g. as CSV, import the CSV into Excel, and then do Copy + Special Paste -> Transpose in Excel

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to go from Tom Kyte - works like Postgres \G or MySQL +x

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:249321700346816237

```
ops$tkyte%ORA9IR2> create or replace type myScalarType as object
  2  ( rnum number, cname varchar2(30), val varchar2(4000) )
  3  /

Type created.

ops$tkyte%ORA9IR2> create or replace type myTableType as table of myScalarType
  2  /

Type created.

ops$tkyte%ORA9IR2>
ops$tkyte%ORA9IR2> create or replace
  2  function cols_as_rows( p_query in varchar2 ) return myTableType
  3  -- this function is designed to be installed ONCE per database, and
  4  -- it is nice to have ROLES active for the dynamic sql, hence the
  5  -- AUTHID CURRENT_USER
  6  authid current_user
  7  -- this function is a pipelined function -- meaning, it'll send
  8  -- rows back to the client before getting the last row itself
  9  -- in 8i, we cannot do this
 10  PIPELINED
 11  as
 12      l_theCursor     integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
 13      l_columnValue   varchar2(4000);
 14      l_status        integer;
 15      l_colCnt        number default 0;
 16      l_descTbl       dbms_sql.desc_tab;
 17      l_rnum          number := 1;
 18  begin
 19          -- parse, describe and define the query.  Note, unlike print_table
 20          -- i am not altering the session in this routine.  the
 21          -- caller would use TO_CHAR() on dates to format and if they
 22          -- want, they would set cursor_sharing.  This routine would
 23          -- be called rather infrequently, I did not see the need
 24          -- to set cursor sharing therefore.
 25      dbms_sql.parse(  l_theCursor,  p_query, dbms_sql.native );
 26      dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl );
 27      for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
 28          dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000 );
 29      end loop;
 30
 31          -- Now, execute the query and fetch the rows.  Iterate over
 32          -- the columns and "pipe" each column out as a separate row
 33          -- in the loop.  increment the row counter after each
 34          -- dbms_sql row
 35      l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);
 36      while ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 )
 37      loop
 38          for i in 1 .. l_colCnt
 39          loop
 40              dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );
 41              pipe row
 42              (myScalarType( l_rnum, l_descTbl(i).col_name, l_columnValue ));
 43          end loop;
 44          l_rnum := l_rnum+1;
 45      end loop;
 46
 47          -- clean up and return...
 48      dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_theCursor);
 49      return;
 50  end cols_as_rows;
 51  /

Function created.

ops$tkyte%ORA9IR2>
ops$tkyte%ORA9IR2> select *
  2    from TABLE( cols_as_rows('select *
  3                                from emp
  4                               where rownum = 1') );

      RNUM CNAME                          VAL
---------- ------------------------------ --------------------
         1 EMPNO                          7369
         1 ENAME                          SMITH
         1 JOB                            CLERK
         1 MGR                            7902
         1 HIREDATE                       17-DEC-80
         1 SAL                            800
         1 COMM
         1 DEPTNO                         20
```