# Flatten table to get unique Email Addresses

Tags: sql, oracle, unique

I have a table that contains 4 fields. first_client_number, first_client_email, second_client_number, second_client_email. Something like:

| first_client_number | first_client_email | second_client_number | second_client_email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | na1@na.com | 2222 | na2@na.com |
| 3333 | na3@na.com | 3333 | na3@na.com |
| 4444 | na4@na.com | 4444 | na4@na.com |
| 6666 | na6@na.com | 7777 | na7@na.com |
| etc |  |  |  |

Where:

- the first client number and the second client number can be different
- the first client number and the second client number can be the same

I want to get a unique list of all emails so that I have one column that shows the client number and a second column to show the clients email address. How do I flatten the table to get my desired result?

I am querying in Oracle v.12

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle show columns as row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504172/oracle-show-columns-as-row)

Answer (score 1):

The fields in your description don't match the fields defined as column headers on your table...  in the question: I'm assuming your table column headers are correct

One method would be to use an "UNPIVOT"

Doc link: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html

But given the limited columns I think this is easiest; splitting the data and using a simple union

```
SELECT first_client_number as client_number, first_client_email as Client_email
FROM table

UNION

SELECT second_client_number, second_client_email
FROM Table
```

Notes:

- we can't define first or second so we have to generate an alias for the columns.  We don't need to alias the 2nd query as it inherits the names from the first.
- It assumes the data types for the 1st and 2nd columns respectively are identical.
- We don't use `union all` as we don't want to keep duplicates and `union` will perform a distinct on the result set eliminating the undesired duplicates.

Comment: thanks for pointing mismatching field names. I have fixed it. The intention was that they should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot and select distinct:

```
with
  test_data (first_client_number, first_client_email,
             second_client_number, second_client_email) as (
    select 1111, 'na1@na.com', 2222, 'na2@na.com' from dual union all
    select 3333, 'na3@na.com', 3333, 'na3@na.com' from dual union all
    select 4444, 'na4@na.com', 4444, 'na4@na.com' from dual union all
    select 6666, 'na6@na.com', 7777, 'na7@na.com' from dual
  )
--   End of test data (not part of the actual query); remove and replace
--   table name with the actual table name
select  distinct client_number, client_email
from    test_data
unpivot (   (client_number, client_email)
            for col in (
                         (first_client_number, first_client_email),
                         (second_client_number, second_client_email)
                       )
        )
;


CLIENT_NUMBER   CLIENT_EMAIL
-------------   ---------------------
         3333   na3@na.com
         4444   na4@na.com
         2222   na2@na.com
         6666   na6@na.com
         7777   na7@na.com
         1111   na1@na.com
```

Comment: can you see me answer below?

Comment: @Pugzly - If what you mean is that you tried my query with your additional data, and you didn't get the expected/required result, then: I just tried on my system, and I get the correct result. It is very likely that you just didn't look carefully enough; since the output is not ordered, the rows may not appear where you expect them, but they are all there. Alternatively, order by something (at the end of the query) and then look again.

Comment: my mistake and apologies