# How to convert row to column for below scenario

Tags: oracle

iam trying to convert rows to columns in SQL. the below is my data.

```
id1  id2  id3
---------------
100  101  103
```

i want to populate output below. could you please help me out.

```
output:
-----
100
101
103
```

tried below:

```
select * from(select value, columnname from test_109)
src
pivot
(value for columnname in(id,id_1,id_2)
)piv;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle show columns as row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504172/oracle-show-columns-as-row)

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is

```
select id1 from test_109 union all
select id2 from test_109 union all
select id3 from test_109;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `UNPIVOT` (not `PIVOT`):

```sql
SELECT value
FROM   test_109
UNPIVOT (value for columnname in(id1,id2,id3));
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_109 (id1, id2, id3) AS
SELECT 100, 101, 103 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 100 |
> | 101 |
> | 103 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=470405c7fdb132c42eb60f7e983abb11)*